# Error "Object required" While calling the function in HTML linked to embedded vbscript

Tags: html, sql-server, vbscript

Out of interest i am trying to create an account creation html which will store the entered data in SQL server, and I am using VbScript.

The VBScript is executing very well, if it is run independently in .VBS fromat, But When I am embedding It in the HTML, Nothing is happening.

What can be the problem??
The code is below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/vbscript">
<!--
...
<!-- This part connects to SQL Server //-->
...
Function addUser(Name,Age,Username,Pass,Repass)

if (pass = Repass) Then
connection.execute("INSERT INTO [NewSN].[dbo].[UserInfo] ([Name],[Age],[Username],[Pass]) VALUES ('"&Name &"','" &Age &"','"&Username &"','" &pass &"')")
    MsgBox "You are now added!"
Else
    MsgBox "Password Mismatch!"&vbnewline&"Please Re-enter!"
end if 
End Function

//-->
</script>

</head>

<body>
<h1><b><u>NewSocialNetwork</b></u><br></h1>
<h2>Sign Up</h2>

<p>
<Pre>
<font face="Times New Roman" size="3">Please enter the details:
Name:       <input type="text" name="Name">
Age:        <input type="text" name="Age">
User Name:  <input type="text" name="UserName">
Password:       <input type="password" name="Pass">
Retype Password:    <input type="password" name="RePass"></font>
<input type="button" onclick="addUser Name.value,Age.Value,Username.value,Pass.value,Repass.value" value="Sign up" />
</pre>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have edited the code as shown above. Now in the function call, I am getting an error **"Object Required"**  And If i remove ***".value"*** from the calling line, the execution is succesful but the entered data is not being displayed in the database; **[Object]** is displayed instead of the actual field values.

What could be wrong? How do i add the object?

Comment: For one thing there's on `=` between `onclick` and the string with the function call.

Comment: @ansgar that is a typo. I already had in my actual script. Anything else?

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers please chech the edited question, I changed the call syntax of function

Comment: Please add the exact error message to your question. Also, which line exactly is raising the error, and which IE version are you using?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I Have figured what was going wrong. I needed to create a form and use that object.